# I've combined dust with other, valuable UTXO's. Can I de-link them?

Tags: privacy, forced-address-reuse

Long ago, when Bitcoin was only a geeky novelty with very little fiat value, I mined some BTC in a mining pool. There were several transactions resulting in (fractions of) newly generated coins sent to my single address.

I recently found my old private key and swept it into a new wallet. Looking at the blockchain explorer, I now see that a few of the old address' inputs were single-Satoshi dust transactions.

I understand that I could have simply not spent those specific UTXO's, but now it's too late. Is there any method for me to minimize any privacy (correlation / de-anonymization) issues now that it's done?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider running them all through a [mixer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_tumbler)